# Why is the "1" after sum necessary to avoid a syntax error

Tags: python, function, sum

Why does this work:

```
def hamming_distance(dna_1,dna_2):
    hamming_distance = sum(1 for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2) if a != b)
    return hamming_distance
```

As opposed to this:

```
def hamming_distance(dna_1,dna_2):
    hamming_distance = sum(for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2) if a != b)
    return hamming_distance
```

I get this error:

```
 Input In [90]
    hamming_distance = sum(for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2) if a != b)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expected the function to work without the 1 after the ()

Comment: *"I expected the function to work without the 1 after the ()"*   Why? what exactly `sum(for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2) if a != b)` is supposed to sum?

Comment: Why exactly did you expect that? What did you expect it to mean?

Comment: You can avoid writing `1` **and** the condition if you remember that Python booleans are integers: `sum(a != b for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2))`

Comment: @DeepSpace: Although I should note, that's slightly more obscure, and definitely slower on CPython (both because it has to freeze and resume the generator for every pair, not just for pairs passing the test, and because `bool`s prevent `sum`'s fast path for small exact `int`s from being used).

Comment: @ShadowRanger unless that generator is going to produce millions of items, I'm putting my money that the difference is so neglectable that it does not exist.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm getting `0.5829065` vs `0.8495115` for one million elements when using `range(1_000_000)` for both containers, so about `0.27` seconds per million elements.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Actually, the implementation detail of `bool`s not being accelerated used to make a pretty big difference, [but they added `bool` to the fast path in 3.9, so in 3.9+ the difference is much smaller](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80962). I forgot that change had actually landed (I meant to qualify the statement with "some versions of CPython", because I knew the change was coming, I just forgot it was already there). I'm not really arguing for it on a performance basis though; using `bool`s for numeric values is just being a teensy bit too clever, so I try to avoid it.

Comment: Admittedly, the use in `sum` is probably the least objectionable use of `bool`s as numbers I've seen. The worst being indexing a `tuple` of two elements on the result of a `bool` comparison, which ends up looking like a `numpy` masking, but not quite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working expression can be unrolled into something like this:

```
hamming_distance = 0
for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2):
    if a != b:
        hamming_distance += 1
```

Without a number after `+=`, what should Python add? It doesn't know, and neither do we.

If this "unrolled" syntax or your code's relationship to it is new to you, probably start by reading up on *list comprehensions,* which generalize into *generator expressions* (which is what you have).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a generator expression. Generator expressions must *produce* a value (some expression to the left of the first `for`). Without it, you're saying "please sum all the lack-of-values not-produced by this generator expression".

Ask yourself:

- What does a genexpr that produces nothing even mean?
- What is `sum` summing when it's being passed a series of *absolute nothing*?

You *could* write a shorter genexpr with the same effect with:

```
hamming_distance = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2))
```

since `bool`s have integer values of `1` (for `True`) and `0` (for `False`), so it would still work, but it would be slower than `sum(1 for a, b in zip(dna_1, dna_2) if a != b)` (which produces fewer values for `sum` to work on and, at least on some versions of Python, allows `sum` to operate faster, since it has a fast path for summing small *exact* `int` types that `bool` breaks).